# Flutter how to use context outside build widget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to use context outside Widget Build. I have a a simple function in which I am showing showDialog which need context.

Code

```
 check() async {

    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

    String imi = await storage.read(key: "imei");
    //print(imi);
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Center(
              child: const SpinKitWave(
                  color: kPrimaryColor, type: SpinKitWaveType.center));
        });

    if (imi == "loginhuavaha") {
      setState(() {
        this._query();
        checkLogin = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

I need to use a context but outside Build Widget any solution how can I use ?

Comment: You can do it in statefull widget

Answer (score 0):

Define this `check()` function inside the class.

Answer (score 0):

When calling this function you need to pass the context to it like this.

```dart
  check(BuildContext context) async {             // <- Here

    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

    String imi = await storage.read(key: "imei");
    //print(imi);
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: false,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return Center(
              child: const SpinKitWave(
                  color: kPrimaryColor, type: SpinKitWaveType.center));
        });

    if (imi == "loginhuavaha") {
      setState(() {
        this._query();
        checkLogin = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: i am calling check function in INIT state so I cant pass content is thek